# How to get last folder (sorted alphabetically in descending order and matching a pattern) using ls/find/etc?

Tags: find, ls

So I have these filesystem structure

```
/my.parent
  -> my.folder1
     -> my-file1.txt
  -> my.folder2
     -> my-file2.txt
  -> another-folder-here
     -> another-file.txt
```

Using this series of commands:

```
ls -r /my.parent/my.folder* | head -n 1 | rev | cut -c 2- | rev
```

**It returns the full path to my.folder2 which is what I want.** My problem is that if there's only 1 folder matching the pattern (e.g. I delete/move my.folder1), I get a listing of the contents of my.folder2 instead of getting the full path.

Any ideas on how to fix it so it works in all cases? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try `ls`'s `-d` option?

Comment: I also have to changed the "cut -c 2-" into "cut -c 1-" to make it work. thanks for the tip. :)

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `rev`? `rev | cut -c 1- | rev` would keep the input unchanged, and with `cut -c 2-` you would be removing the last character from the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get `ls` to display the folder name instead of listing its contents, use its `-d` argument such as:

```
ls -ld ~
```

Answer (score 2):

Without `ls`, in bash, or some other shell that has arrays (this should work even with names that have funny characters in them):

```
$ names=( my.parent/my.folder* ); echo ${names[-1]}
my.parent/my.folder2
```

Without arrays (not so robust against funny characters, but saves a fork of the `ls`):

```
$ printf "%s\n" my.parent/my.folder*  | tail -1
my.parent/my.folder2
```

Answer (score 0):

[Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

The shell expands `/my.parent/my.folder*` to the list of subdirectories of `/my.parent` whose name starts with `my.folder` in alphabetical order. Calling `ls` does nothing useful.

To pick the last element of the list, if your shell has arrays, put the list in an array and pick the last element.

```
directories=(/my.parent/my.folder*)
last_directory="${directories[${#directories}-1]}"
```

If your shell doesn't have arrays, you can do this through the positional parameters.

```
set -- /my.parent/my.folder*
eval "last_directory=\${$#}"
```

This overwrites the current positional parameters. To avoid this, use a function.

```
set_to_last () {
  eval "$1=\${$#}"
}
set_to_last last_directory /my.parent/my.folder*
```

Note that all the code in this answer assumes that there is at least one match.